# Ranging beacons stops when new Android Intent is open

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I have created an Application, which range beacons and calculates the position when more than three beacons are ranged.

The Problem is, that when I want to show the position, it's necessary to start a new Intent, so the main  activity is not still in Foreground. After approximately 5 seconds the ranging of the beacons stops, and my position calculating also because the distances of the beacons doesn't change any more.

Is there any possibility to continue ranging beacons? I've tried to start an async task in my main activity, but it doesn't work, maybe there is a mistake, i don't know.

Here is my Code of the async task and the OnBeaconServiceConnect():

```
public class Monitor_Screen extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer,
    SensorEventListener {

private class asyncThread extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, BeaconManager> {


    @Override
    protected BeaconManager doInBackground(Activity... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Thread.currentThread().setName("BeaconManagerThread");

        Application myApplication = new Application();
        // BeaconManager
        myBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(myApplication);
        myBeaconManager
                .getBeaconParsers()
                .add(new BeaconParser()
                        .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        myBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
        myBeaconManager.bind(Monitor_Screen.this);



        // Region
        myRegion = new Region("all beacons", null, null, null); 
        startService(Monitor_Screen.this.getIntent());
        return myBeaconManager;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    // // range beacons on connect

    try {
        myBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(myRegion);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    myBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {

        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons,
                Region myRegion) {

            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Iterator<Beacon> myIterator = beacons.iterator();
                while (myIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Beacon tempBeacon = myIterator.next();
                    MyBeacon myBeacon = new MyBeacon(tempBeacon.getId1(),
                            tempBeacon.getId2(), tempBeacon.getId3(),
                            tempBeacon.getBluetoothAddress(), tempBeacon
                                    .getRssi(), tempBeacon.getDistance(),
                            tempBeacon.getTxPower(), System
                                    .currentTimeMillis(),
                            new Position(0, 0));
                    boolean isIn = false;
                    for (MyBeacon blub : myVector) {
                        if (blub.getBTAdress().equals(
                                myBeacon.getBTAdress())) {
                            isIn = true;
                            blub.distance = myBeacon.getDistance();
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isIn)
                        myVector.add(myBeacon);
                }
            }

            logBeaconData();
            for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis()
                        - myVector.get(i).getTimeStamp() > 10000) {
                    myVector.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        myBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(myRegion);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myBeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have beacon ranging continue in the background is to set up beacon ranging in a custom `android.app.Application` class, and have it forward the callbacks to your `Activity` to update the display only if that `Activity` is in the foreground.

You can see an example of doing this in the reference application for the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

Below is an excerpt from the custom `android.app.Application` class where this is set up.  Note that ranging is set up once, and will continue for the whole lifecycle of the application.  The ranging callback is passed to the `mRangingActivity` if it exists, so it can do any UI processing necessary.

```
public class BeaconReferenceApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, RangeNotifier {
...

    public void onCreate() {
        mAllBeaconsRegion = new Region("all beacons", null, null, null);
        mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        mBackgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);     
        mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, mAllBeaconsRegion);
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> arg0, Region arg1) {
        if (mRangingActivity != null) {
            mRangingActivity.didRangeBeaconsInRegion(arg0, arg1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "entered region.  starting ranging");
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(mAllBeaconsRegion);
            mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start ranging");
        }
    }

...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me. I started a new Project and tested the ReferenceApplication, but it doesn't work. The Application crashs :(

Comment: Try running an unmodified version of the reference application.  If you see a crash, please paste a link to a stack trace.